# For what ist the epsg-file in the "share/proj" subfolder of the QGIS - installation used for?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, epsg

In the "share/proj" subfolder of the QGIS-installation there is an epsg-file with  definitions of the epsg-codes like this:

```
# DHDN / 3-degree Gauss-Kruger zone 3
<31467> +proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=9 +k=1 +x_0=3500000 +y_0=0 +datum=potsdam +units=m +no_defs  <>
```

For reprojecting layers (permanent and on the fly) the definitions from this file seem to be irrelevant as the definitions of the srs.db seem to be used.

Does it make sense to update this file if custom changes had been done to the srs.db file or is this file not important for QGIS as the srs.db is used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The files in the share/proj subfolder are used by proj.exe and cs2cs.exe if you use something like `+init=epsg:31467` as projection string.

If you use GDAL commands or processing algos with `-t_srs EPSG:31467`, the data is taken from the csv files in the share/gdal subfolder. But you can use the `+init` syntax as well to get the definition from the PROJ database.

Internal QGIS commands and processing algos use the srs.db from \apps\qgis\resources .

So it really depends on what you are doing.